# MySQL query nested in an if statement - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Can a MySQL query string be nested inside an `if` statement as shown below?

```
if (mysql_query($queryString)) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return $error;
}
```

If this is not possible, what is the best way to make sure that the query has been executed by the query that is inside the `if` statement?

(I know that MySQL has been depreciated now, but to change it across the site that I am building would be far to difficult and long-winded)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it depends on the what kind of statement you're doing

For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: The statement that I am writing is an `INSERT INTO` query, so I will be able to nest this within an `if`?

Comment: And also - will it still preform the query inside the if?

Comment: Yes the query will still execute if you put it in the if.

Comment: Thank you very much for that, I will mark your answer as correct.